# Can I watch The Force Awakens without having previously watched the earlier films?

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order, the-force-awakens

If I have not seen any of the previous Star Wars movies, would it be possible to watch *The Force Awakens* and fully understand it? Does it provide enough of the background for me to know what is going on?

Comment: I think so yeah. Will you enjoy it equally as someone who has seen the previous ones ? No.

Comment: You can not *fully* understand. If you don't have time to watch all the previous movies, you can watch the summary videos on Youtube.

Comment: You can, but a lot of the story is based on the legacy of the original characters, so I'd recommend watching episodes 4-6 first. You can definitely skip the prequels (episodes 1-3).

Comment: Gosh. I reckon the optimum way to enjoy it is to see Star Wars as a child, *then* wait 16 years for the prequels and be crushingly disappointed, *then* wait 7 years thinking that’s it for Star Wars movies until Lucas somehow finds four billion reasons to sell it to Disney, *then* avoid watching the trailers, *then* go see it. So, uh, try to do that?

Comment: Just curious - how'd you make it this long without seeing even one Star Wars movie?

Comment: It actually helps if you haven't watched the other ones, especially A New Hope. Otherwise, you risk being bored by an identical plot.

Comment: Ah, I see.  No need to really persuade ...just get them in a room and show the movies! "Do or do not, there is no try". :P

Comment: @Mithrandir - True, but that meant (to me) that either you (or, like you said, someone you know) hasn't seen any of them...and I was just curious how/why (not in a condescending manner at all, simply curious). Cheers mate!

Comment: @BruceWayne: I didn’t see the original Star Wars trilogy until I was 13, in 1994. Of course, then you could still get them without CGI travesties inserted.

Comment: @BruceWayne I haven't seen them yet aswell. And anyway feels like knowing the story since I'm loving it. But I for my self wan't to see them chronological ordered and without too big gaps within. But never had the time to do it. Its something on my "Why I'm here?"-Checklist. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir You did say "I" in the question title, so naturally we assumed it was you yourself who hadn't seen the movies. This leads to another question, are you the son of rand-al'thor?

Comment: @Mithrandir ::sigh:: because rand-al'thor also admitted to not having seen the films. Although I believe by now he has caught up.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes, nothing prevents you from watching it without any other movies whatsoever, but you will miss some important backstory and much of the emotional impact of the movie if you do not watch the original trilogy first. The prequels can be skipped entirely.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The earlier films are not strictly necessary, but recommended.

You'd get more enjoyment out of watching Star Wars if you watch TFA after watching the other films, although you *could* watch it on its own. For the following reasons.

- If you're into Star Wars to the extent of being interested in seeing the new film, you'll probably enjoy the previous ones too. I assume you're not just going to see it 'because it's new' but because you're interested in the franchise as a whole.
- There are numerous in-jokes, Easter eggs, and references in TFA which you won't get without having seen the previous films.
- If you enjoy TFA, then you'll probably want to see the other films as well, but watching them afterwards would be less enjoyable: many plot twists will already have been revealed and so on.
- If you like the special effects in TFA, you'll be disappointed by watching the other films afterwards as, being much older, they have less up-to-date effects.

---

There's a very thorough answer to the same question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Do-I-need-to-watch-previous-Star-Wars-films-to-watch-Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens), which I've more or less copied here:

> - First of all, if you're about to dive into one of the biggest global pop culture phenomenons anyway, then to really get the full experience you need to witness the previous six films. At the point you've decided to see the new film, in a general sense you need to do so in the most informed way and in the context of the overall phenomenon.
> - Second, there will be lots of relationship details, inside jokes, dialogue call-backs, Easter Eggs, and references that you will not understand if you don't watch the first six movies. Yes, someone can just explain it all to you in a quick, simple way, but there's no way they'll get all of the details and dialogue etc into their explanation. Any detailed explanation or written backstory that is sufficient to prepare you for seeing Star Wars: The Force Awakens will take so much time to read and remember that you may as well spend the time and energy to actually experience the six movies.
> - Third, the experience you have when watching the new upcoming sequel will be dramatically enhanced by having seen the previous films. From a purely artistic sense, these are amazing films and each one of them is made better by the larger context of the other films. So from an entertainment perspective, you need to treat yourself to the other movies before treating yourself to the newest one.
> - Fourth, the odds are that after you see The Force Awakens, you'll want to see the other films anyway. But seeing them afterwards will create a weird disconnect in the storytelling. If you start watching the earlier films afterwards, then you might enjoy them less or have your enjoyment of the new sequel reduced after the fact as your confusions and different experiences with the earlier films add on to the original experience with the new film.
> - Fifth, since you're probably going to end up watching the earlier movies if you watch The Force Awakens, the difference in visual effects will distract you. The fact is that the new movie will have visual effects conforming to today's standards. So if you witness that, and then afterwards try to go back to the earlier films, you are likely going to be more inclined to notice a lot of the limitations of visual effects in the earlier movies.
>
> Now, technically **do you really HAVE to see the first six films in order to even be able to sit through and enjoy the new movie? Probably not.** You can probably watch the new film and keep up with it well enough, assuming you've at least heard the very basics of what Star Wars is. The mythology and details might be confusing to you at times, but most likely it'll either end up being explained by whatever is happening, or it will pass by and you'll forget and not care because the story keeps moving forward and you can mostly keep up.
>
> But that's no way to experience a movie -- "mostly keeping up" and "mostly getting over any confusion." And it's especially no way to experience a Star Wars movie.

---

I also found [a report](http://www.buzzfeed.com/agh/bb-8-sucks#.xdJ4Oy5r1) from some poor soul who went to see *The Force Awakens* without having seen any of the previous Star Wars films and wrote down some of her reactions. However, people seem to think she's lying about her reactions or about her SW knowledge, so I removed the quotes of her reactions from my answer.

Comment: “What planet is this? Is this Earth?” Oh for crying out loud. ***A LONG TIME AGO, IN A GALAXY FAR, FAR AWAY.*** So no, not earth.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hey, these aren't my words! I'm answering the question, by showing what happens if you see TFA without knowing the previous SW stuff.

Comment: @randal'thor: yeah I know. My fury is directed at the Buzzfeed chump.

Comment: Wow, that report seems more like an argument for paying attention to advertising, than for watching 13 hours of other film. The new characters names were not only plastered over ads and merch, but said *very early* in the new movie. Pay attention, BuzzFeed noob.

Comment: @CreationEdge Not everyone cares about all this Star Wars crap, you know! ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor I learned their names *on accident* just by shopping for toys! I don't know how you can escape it without being a hermit!

Comment: @CreationEdge I escaped it completely before I got involved with this site. Didn't know Darth Vader = Anakin Skywalker = Luke's father; hadn't even heard the names.

Comment: Downvoted for having insufficient cultural knowledge. :P

Comment: @randal'thor = **Darth Vader is Luke's father**???? Did you REALLY have to spoil it for me???

Comment: @DVK Rofl. I did think for a moment before putting that in a comment, but it's knowledge one should probably have before going to see TFA, so if anyone interested in this question is *actually* spoiled by this info, it'll be good for them anyway!

Comment: @randal'thor Born yesterday, you were?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Does canon establish that in the intervening time no planet decided to hyperdrive itself to a different galaxy?  Because in the Star Wars galaxy the sudden and violent annihilation of planets _does_ seem to be a common enough problem that a wealthy planet might plausibly decide "this place is insane, I'm out".  And then the rest writes itself.

Comment: @aroth: well true. Oh god. *Star Wars* and *Battlestar Galactica* are the same universe.

Answer (score 12):

### Yes, you can watch and enjoy *The Force Awakens* independent of the other films, and understand what's happening

There are numerous reports of people watching *The Force Awakens* without having seen any of the previous films, and still enjoying the movie. There are also reports of people who did *not* enjoy any of the other 6 films, and also seeing this movie and enjoying it.

The film is structured in a way that the history of characters and their relationships are disclosed in such a way to provide sufficient background for the existing movie.

However, if you've seen the other films then you're more likely to notice Easter Eggs, references, and throwbacks to the previous films. Not noticing that shouldn't affect your enjoyment of the film. (I don't believe the [record-shattering opening box office](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=starwars7.htm) revenue can be attributed solely to existing Star Wars fans.)

Here's what the director JJ Abrams said about this in a [Wired interview](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/star-wars-force-awakens-jj-abrams-interview/):

> ***How much of The Force Awakens  is geared toward welcoming people back to the Star Wars franchise versus starting something completely new? How do you strike a balance between those two imperatives?***
>
> We wanted to tell **a story that had its own self-contained beginning, middle, and end** but at the same time, like A New Hope, implied a history that preceded it and also hinted at a future to follow. When Star Wars first came out, it was a film that both allowed the audience to understand a new story but also to infer all sorts of exciting things that might be. In that first movie, Luke wasn’t necessarily the son of Vader, he wasn’t necessarily the brother of Leia, but it was all possible. The Force Awakens has this incredible advantage, not just of a passionate fan base but also of a backstory that is familiar to a lot of people. We’ve been able to use what came before in a very organic way, because we didn’t have to reboot anything. We didn’t have to come up with a backstory that would make sense; it’s all there. **But these new characters, which Force is very much about, find themselves in new situations—so even if you don’t know anything about Star Wars, you’re right there with them.** If you are a fan of Star Wars, what they experience will have added meaning.

So, as you can see, it was also *designed* to be self-contained, so that a new audience, and even a new generation, could see the film and be introduced to the Star Wars universe.

Comment: Yes!  Also, keep in mind that ANH also started [In medias res](https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Terms/inmediasres.html). Watching ANH with my kids I was reminded of that "why this" "who's that"...

Comment: @zipquincy Yes. I recently went through the other movies with my wife, who has never seen them before, and there are a lot of those questions in those films. But as each trilogy goes on, they generally get answered!

Comment: “In that first movie, Luke wasn’t necessarily the son of Vader” JJ! Spoilers!

Comment: Contemplating how difficult it would be for that to not already to have been spoiled if I hadn't seen the movies yet.. maybe if I had time traveled past the last 30 years or so.

Comment: Understand most of what's happening, I agree.  However there is that one scene where someone dies, and then the film immediately cuts to someone else in a completely different location (with no way of seeing what had just happened) looking deeply pained for several seconds.  It's hard to understand what's going on in that one without the previous movies to explain who's force-sensitive and what that means.  And also another bit where Ren refers to a particular helmet as 'grandfather'.

Comment: @aroth Seemed pretty clear to me. They did the same thing is Age of Ultron without even having The Force.